# Consuming a DjangoRestFramework data from an external Unity C# application

Tags: c#, django, unity-game-engine, django-rest-framework

**Serializing data with `DjangoRestFramework`**

I've serialized my Django users model to turn on in a small API with `DjangoRestFramework`

And in my web browser is the following:

[image]

From my a Unity C# application I am consuming these users data in JSON, via this code section:

```
//This methods loads the information of the client and validates if it is correct.
        private IEnumerator LoadInfo() {

            string inputFieldName = userInputName.text;
            string password = userPassword.text;
            if (inputFieldName != "")
            {
                urlUsuario(inputFieldName);
                WWW info = new WWW(url);
                yield return info;

                try
                {
                    jsonString = info.text;

                    Debug.Log(url);

                    Debug.Log(jsonString);

                    itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(jsonString);
                    string jsonName = (string)itemData[0]["username"];

                    if ((jsonName.ToString() == inputFieldName))
                    {
                        string nameJson = (string)itemData[0]["username"];
                        userName.text = nameJson;
                        string picUrl = (string)itemData[0]["avatar"];
                        LoginMenu.enabled = false;
                        InitialMenu.enabled = true;
                        StartCoroutine(loadProfilePic(picUrl));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ErrorMenuConnection();
                    e.ToString();
                    Debug.Log("Failed Connection");
                    Debug.Log(jsonString);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ErrorMenu();
            }

        }
```

but I get this message

[image]

What happened is the following:

I need to access the diferent fields of my JSON, by example:
`username`, `password`, and anothers.
But in the past I had an array of json data structure

```
[{"last_name": "Agudelo Marenco",  "slug": "pablo",  "first_name": "Pablo Andres", "username": "pablo", "password": "+FtK7BfBFec="}]
```

And with this json data structure the program worked. But my current RestFramework json implementation I show above is not working properly
because I cannot access to the different attributes in the JSON.

Comment: that's a lot to read. Is there a TLDR?

Comment: @e4c5 it's true, my apologies for the long to question, but I unknown how to summarize. :(  Do you want that I resume the question ?

Comment: Very hard to understand what you are asking. Can you put the class you want to serialize/convert to Json and I will help do that.

Comment: @Programmer I have been simplifying my question. Any help would be appreciated.